# ¿Por qué el toggler de Bootstrap 5 no vuelve a contraer el navbar?

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un navbar hecho con Bootstrap y en el responsive se agrega un toggler, que funciona para desplegar hacia abajo, pero no vuelve a contraerse al hacer clic. ¿Qué debo hacer?

[image: navbar]

El código del navbar es:

```html
<nav class="margenes navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #cfeafd;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Veterinaria</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="margen-down navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Veterinari@s</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dueñ@s</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopta</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Como ven, se despliega hacia abajo, pero al tocar, no vuelve a su posición original, y no sé como poder arreglarlo.

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar el código, como texto? Además, te referís al [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/) o al menú hamburguesa, como [toggler](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#toggler)?

Comment: Listo @padaleiana ya lo adjunte, y perdon, me refiero al toggler, me confundi los terminos, mala mia

Comment: Una última: ¿podrías adjuntar cómo estás importando bootstrap? ¿estás usando JS también?

Comment: Listo @padaleiana, ya lo adjunte al post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sucede que estás utilizando `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`, por lo tanto ya no es necesario utilizar `popper.min.js` + `bootstrap.min.js` ya que ambos están combinados en el primer script. Es como decir

> `bootstrap.min.js` + `popper.min.js` = `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`.

Por lo tanto, quedaría de esta manera:

```html
<!-- CSS agregado para mostrar el navbar con estilos-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="margenes navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #cfeafd;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Veterinaria</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="margen-down navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Veterinari@s</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dueñ@s</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopta</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**SI ESTAS EN UNA VERSION ANTERIOR DE BOOTSTRAP DIRIGETE Y BUSCA LA NUEVA
EJEMPLO ESTAMOS EN EL 28/03/2023 (dd/MM/yyyy) Y BOOTSTRAP TIENE LA VERSION**

[image: ESTE ES MI EJEMPLO DE QUE TRATO DE DECIR]

**ENTONCES AGREGO ESE CODIGO A MI  EN SRC=""
ASÍ DEBERÁ QUEDAR:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```